# While installing Ubuntu I used replace Windows with Ubuntu option. Did it delete my private data?

Tags: ntfs, disk, data-recovery

I had 3 Partitions:

- Local Disk `C:` with Windows installed
- `D:` and `E:` with my data.

While installing Ubuntu, I used:

> Replace Windows With Ubuntu Option

Have I lost my data in `D:` and `E:` also? If not, where are they? I am not able to find them.

Please help, I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: can you add the outcome of `sudo fdisk -l` please?

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry to say but yes, the D:, E: and any other letter assigned partitions are gone. The option mentions what it will do:

[image]

**This will delete all of your Windows 7 programs, documents, photos, music and any other files.**

And it will leave you with a hard drive partitioned in 2 pieces, the root `/` partition and the swap.

What you need to do quickly is, without using the partition (Or at least not using it even further) is to burn the Ubuntu image on a pen drive. Preferably do this on an other computer), run it from there on the PC you want to recover those deleted partitions from and install `testdisk`. After installing, run it from the terminal:

```
sudo testdisk
```

Now tell it to try to recover the partitions. If it succeeds, your Ubuntu partitions will be lost and the Windows partitions will be recovered.

Note that after a testdisk recovery you will not be able to boot Windows or Ubuntu from the drive but you may be able to recover most (but probably not all) of your data from successfully recovered partition.